# How to know coloring is complete on the sprite?

Tags: unity-game-engine, sprite

I am trying to make color game in that there are three object border, 3d cube, and a pointer(tube), here i'm painting a 3d cube with a pointer by changing its texture and put a sprite on the cube so i want to detect the condition while i almost complete the coloring inside the sprite border how can i do that in unity?

Like in this image

[image: 1]

I want to know how to detect almost complete coloring within the boundry sprite.

Comment: Count the areas as you fill them in. When it matches the needed amount its done?

Comment: I would recommend [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xss4__kgYiY) tutorial from code monkey. It shows a simple paint process as well as a simple method to calculate how much was painted.

Answer (score 0):

To detect if the coloring inside the sprite border is almost complete, you can use a combination of Unity's built-in collision detection and image processing techniques. Something like this:

- First create a sprite mask on the sprite border to mask the cube image. This will allow you to apply an effect to only the area inside the border.
- Then sample the color of each pixel inside the border using the GetPixels method of the Texture2D class. Store these values in an array.
- Calculate the average color of all the pixels in the array.
- Compare the average color to a pre-defined threshold color to determine if the coloring is complete. If the average color is close enough to the threshold color, you can assume that the coloring is complete.

Repeat steps 2-4 in a loop while the player is painting the cube to continuously check if the coloring is complete.

Once the coloring is complete, you can trigger an event or perform some other action in your game.

```
using UnityEngine;

public class ColorDetection : MonoBehaviour
{
    public SpriteRenderer spriteRenderer;
    public Texture2D maskTexture;
    public Color thresholdColor;

    private void Update()
    {
        Color averageColor = GetAverageColor();

        if (IsColorSimilar(averageColor, thresholdColor))
        {
            Debug.Log("Coloring is complete");
        }
    }

    private Color GetAverageColor()
    {
        Texture2D texture = spriteRenderer.sprite.texture;
        Rect spriteRect = spriteRenderer.sprite.rect;

        Color[] maskPixels = maskTexture.GetPixels();
        Color[] spritePixels = texture.GetPixels((int)spriteRect.x, (int)spriteRect.y, (int)spriteRect.width, (int)spriteRect.height);

        int count = 0;
        Color sum = Color.clear;

        for (int i = 0; i < maskPixels.Length; i++)
        {
            if (maskPixels[i].a > 0)
            {
                count++;
                sum += spritePixels[i];
            }
        }

        return sum / count;
    }

    private bool IsColorSimilar(Color a, Color b)
    {
        float delta = 0.05f;
        return Mathf.Abs(a.r - b.r) < delta && Mathf.Abs(a.g - b.g) < delta && Mathf.Abs(a.b - b.b) < delta;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey @javzero, Im not coloring on the sprite, the sprite is a completely different object from the cube behind I'm painting on the cube. so I want to paint the cube only within the sprite that appears on top.